# What will be default isolation level of transaction in case of hibernate with oracle?

Tags: hibernate

i am using Hibernate with oracle . What will be default isolation level if transaction if i don't set it explicitly. **Will it be read_commited (default for oracle)?If i want to set it something else say serilizable how can i set it in hibernate?**

Comment: You can just set it in the connection pool/datasource configuration of your application server. Which server are you using?

Comment: Hi quincy i am more concerned about the default isolation level. It will depend upon the default isolation level of underlying data store which is oracle in this case. Right?

Comment: Right,the default isolation level depends on which db it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Will it be read_commited (default for oracle)?**

Yes

**If i want to set it something else say serilizable how can i set it in hibernate?**

Look for *hibernate.connection.isolation* config param in hibernate manual.
You may also check [session lock](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#buildLockRequest%28org.hibernate.LockOptions%29)